# How can I add a Friendly-id slug through seed.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I am adding thousands of entries to my database through seeds.rb and a CSV file. In order to do so I am using [Fast_Seeder](https://github.com/greyblake/fast_seeder):

```
FastSeeder.seed_csv!(Artist, "artist_sample.csv", :name, :sort_name)
```

I use Friendly-id, and as it is now, it is not creating a slug because I am not feeding it through the file.
How do I go about creating it without having to change the file manually?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Fast_Seeder, but I am with friendly-id. Their docs say the following:

```
# If you're adding FriendlyId to an existing app and need
# to generate slugs for existing users, do this from the
# console, runner, or add a Rake task:
User.find_each(&:save)
```

It would obviously be more efficient to get friendly-id playing nice in the first place, but barring that you can add that the next line. You basically just need to tap validation. I bet `.find_each(&:valid?)` might work too. This leads me to wonder if FastSeeder is creating these records without hitting your validations.

EDIT: Yup, I just dug through their source and they are creating straight through the database. You'll probably need to go the route I outlined above.